RTK Query doesn't generated hooks
I am following the RTK Query guide here https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/rtk-query
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'
import type { Pokemon } from './types'

// Define a service using a base URL and expected endpoints
export const pokemonApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'pokemonApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPokemonByName: builder.query<Pokemon, string>({
      query: (name) => `pokemon/${name}`,
    }),
  }),
})

// Export hooks for usage in functional components, which are
// auto-generated based on the defined endpoints
export const { useGetPokemonByNameQuery } = pokemonApi

I get error at useGetPokemonByNameQuery, it is said that:

The inferred type of 'useGetPokemonByName1Query' cannot be named
without a reference to
'../../../node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/react/buildHooks'.
This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary.ts(2742)

I've tried to google search but not found any solution.
My package.json:
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^5.0.13",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.20",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.20",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.5",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "uuid": "^10.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^10.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.13.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.13.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.1",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.7",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.3.1"
  }


I still haven't completely solved the problem. But i can replicate the problem as the following:

I am copying the source code provided by redux-toolkit team here https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/rtk-query, i don't change anything.
If i start new app in 1 of the two ways described here https://redux-toolkit.js.org/introduction/getting-started: Vite with our Redux+TS template or Next.js using the with-redux template, then i get no errors
Only when i start new app using latest vite described here https://vitejs.dev/guide/, i just run: npm create vite@latest. Then i get the error.

So it can be said that the code provided by the reduxjs toolkit team is error-free, maybe because the config part of vite is different. But I can't figure out what the problem is just based on the error message from typescript. I think this issue can be closed here. Thank you.

import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery, TypedUseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'


type pokemon =
    { username: string, id: number }


export const pokemonApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'pokemonApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/' }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getPokemonByName: builder.query<pokemon, string>({
            query: (name) => `pokemon/${name}`,
        }),
        getPokemon: builder.query<pokemon, void>({
            query: () => `pokemon`,
        }),
    }),
})

export const { 
    useGetPokemonByNameQuery,
     useGetPokemonQuery 
    }: { 
        useGetPokemonByNameQuery: TypedUseQuery<pokemon, string, any>, 
        useGetPokemonQuery: TypedUseQuery<pokemon, void, any> } = pokemonApi


this code helps you

What would you use instead of any if you want strict TS?

This code works perfectly in my case. Thanks.

It will still work.
Nevertheless, if you insist on taking out the error. You could    import everything from buildHooks.
import * as _ from <path_to_buildHooks>

For most cases, path to buildHooks is - "../../node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/react/buildHooks"
While this will solve it, you need to also know that importing everything from a module can lead to potential conflicts if there are overlapping names.

thank you. Yeah, it said that need to import build hooks, but why we have to do it ? why with different config, it works ? And also i copied exactly source code from redux team, so it should work, no need to change anything right ?
